# add new header to iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, google-chrome-extension

how do i add a new header for every outgoing request only for trusted request

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
    var headers = details.requestHeaders;
    console.log("=========BEFORE==========");
    console.log(headers);
    headers.push({
      name: "CSRF",
      value: "CSRFTOKEN"
    });
    console.log("=========AFTER==========");
    console.log(headers);


    },
    {urls: [ "*://*.example.com/*" ]},['requestHeaders']);
```

and even add this header to iframe also

```
var attr ={"src":"http://example.com/test.php"};
var s = zen.utils.createElement(document,"iframe",attr);
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

this is the sample test.php file which prints all the header

```
<?php
 $header=array_merge(getallheaders(),apache_response_headers());
print_r($header);
```

Comment: FYI having code that always adds CSRF tokens to requests to a URL area a great way to get into security issues and pretty much makes CSRF pointless.

Comment: @abraham are there any possible threat in this way ?

Comment: Yes. Now weather there is actually a vulnerability I can't say but security is all about layering and every time you remove a layer the likelihood of attacks being successful increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). Emphasis mine:

> If the optional `opt_extraInfoSpec` array contains the string `'blocking'` (only allowed for specific events), the callback function is handled synchronously. That means that the request is blocked until the callback function returns.
>
> In this case, **the callback can return a [`webRequest.BlockingResponse`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#type-BlockingResponse)** that determines the further life cycle of the request. Depending on the context, this response allows cancelling or redirecting a request (`onBeforeRequest`), cancelling a request or **modifying headers** (**`onBeforeSendHeaders`**, `onHeadersReceived`), or providing authentication credentials (`onAuthRequired`).

So, to modify headers, you need to:

1. Declare that you want to modify the request; that must block the request until you react. You need to add `"blocking"` to the API call.
2. You need a special permission, `"webRequestBlocking"`, for such an operation. Add it to manifest.
3. You need to return the modified headers from the callback.

   ```
   chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
     function(details){
       var headers = details.requestHeaders;
       /* ..modify headers.. */
       return { requestHeaders : headers };
     },
     { urls: [ "*://*.example.com/*" ] },
     [ 'blocking', 'requestHeaders' ]
   );
   ```